# background-attachment: fixed not working on Android Chrome

Tags: android, css, background-image, google-chrome-app, fixed

`background-attachment: fixed` works on Desktop Firefox, Android Firefox, and Desktop Chrome, but it fails on Android Chrome.

Variations of this problem have been reported elsewhere on Stackoverflow, but my example is somewhat different that the others, in that others typically are targeting a background image for the entire viewport, whereas mine is for display as a fixed background viewed behind a div as the user scrolls past it.

Devices tested:
Windows 8.1
Chrome Desktop: Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Android 4.4.4; XT1080 Build/SU6-7.7
Chrome 73.0.3683.90

I've built a simple illustration of this with this CodePen:

https://codepen.io/bmt-codepen/pen/drxbpN

But the code is simple enough:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Fixed Problem</title>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- https://codepen.io/bmt-codepen/pen/drxbpN -->
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

.fixed {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
}

.image1 {
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515694346937-94d85e41e6f0');
}
.image2 {
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534274988757-a28bf1a57c17');
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sapien felis, placerat at sollicitudin sed, eleifend at dolor. Aliquam vulputate dolor quam, sit amet lobortis eros ornare id. Sed et nunc et nulla vestibulum pretium. Nulla sem leo, scelerisque at purus quis, viverra posuere mauris. Pellentesque lobortis porttitor nibh, non venenatis ante efficitur at. Cras leo purus, porttitor eu vestibulum nec, vehicula congue ligula. Aenean ornare ac arcu sit amet vehicula. In molestie, lacus et vulputate vehicula, leo elit consectetur sem, sit amet rutrum mauris elit non dui. Vivamus viverra metus id venenatis commodo. Mauris blandit pellentesque ipsum non sollicitudin. Praesent lobortis velit quis nibh auctor, vitae dapibus elit commodo.</p>
        <p>Donec eget tellus id lacus bibendum cursus. Duis in ultricies urna. Aliquam lacinia, libero sed laoreet rhoncus, metus mauris placerat odio, sollicitudin sollicitudin diam justo vel mauris. Vestibulum non lacus lectus. Aenean interdum sagittis erat in iaculis. Nunc fermentum nisl at dui ultrices, sit amet viverra tellus tincidunt. Praesent at mauris eleifend, aliquet quam id, laoreet justo. Nulla malesuada finibus dui ac luctus. Vestibulum facilisis justo fermentum tincidunt efficitur. Maecenas suscipit ligula neque, sit amet pharetra magna placerat id. Suspendisse potenti. Donec erat ex, gravida sit amet risus nec, cursus facilisis ante. Proin ac massa accumsan, ullamcorper erat ac, laoreet orci. Nulla sollicitudin urna enim, nec porttitor tortor egestas ut. Etiam at justo quis metus maximus ultricies quis eu quam. Integer gravida nisl sem, nec porta tellus consequat eget.</p>
        <p>Quisque cursus, metus a sollicitudin pharetra, lorem odio fringilla arcu, non eleifend urna tellus vel nibh. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam a rutrum est. Etiam et sem vitae sapien tempor rutrum nec vulputate ex. Vestibulum eu vehicula tortor. Curabitur nulla velit, bibendum id varius non, pulvinar lobortis mi. Praesent tempor ex vel odio posuere, sed semper enim lacinia.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed image1">
        <h1>The background fails to remain fixed on Chrome for Android</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sapien felis, placerat at sollicitudin sed, eleifend at dolor. Aliquam vulputate dolor quam, sit amet lobortis eros ornare id. Sed et nunc et nulla vestibulum pretium. Nulla sem leo, scelerisque at purus quis, viverra posuere mauris. Pellentesque lobortis porttitor nibh, non venenatis ante efficitur at. Cras leo purus, porttitor eu vestibulum nec, vehicula congue ligula. Aenean ornare ac arcu sit amet vehicula. In molestie, lacus et vulputate vehicula, leo elit consectetur sem, sit amet rutrum mauris elit non dui. Vivamus viverra metus id venenatis commodo. Mauris blandit pellentesque ipsum non sollicitudin. Praesent lobortis velit quis nibh auctor, vitae dapibus elit commodo.</p>
        <p>Donec eget tellus id lacus bibendum cursus. Duis in ultricies urna. Aliquam lacinia, libero sed laoreet rhoncus, metus mauris placerat odio, sollicitudin sollicitudin diam justo vel mauris. Vestibulum non lacus lectus. Aenean interdum sagittis erat in iaculis. Nunc fermentum nisl at dui ultrices, sit amet viverra tellus tincidunt. Praesent at mauris eleifend, aliquet quam id, laoreet justo. Nulla malesuada finibus dui ac luctus. Vestibulum facilisis justo fermentum tincidunt efficitur. Maecenas suscipit ligula neque, sit amet pharetra magna placerat id. Suspendisse potenti. Donec erat ex, gravida sit amet risus nec, cursus facilisis ante. Proin ac massa accumsan, ullamcorper erat ac, laoreet orci. Nulla sollicitudin urna enim, nec porttitor tortor egestas ut. Etiam at justo quis metus maximus ultricies quis eu quam. Integer gravida nisl sem, nec porta tellus consequat eget.</p>
        <p>Quisque cursus, metus a sollicitudin pharetra, lorem odio fringilla arcu, non eleifend urna tellus vel nibh. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam a rutrum est. Etiam et sem vitae sapien tempor rutrum nec vulputate ex. Vestibulum eu vehicula tortor. Curabitur nulla velit, bibendum id varius non, pulvinar lobortis mi. Praesent tempor ex vel odio posuere, sed semper enim lacinia.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed image2">
        <h1>The background fails to remain fixed on Chrome for Android</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sapien felis, placerat at sollicitudin sed, eleifend at dolor. Aliquam vulputate dolor quam, sit amet lobortis eros ornare id. Sed et nunc et nulla vestibulum pretium. Nulla sem leo, scelerisque at purus quis, viverra posuere mauris. Pellentesque lobortis porttitor nibh, non venenatis ante efficitur at. Cras leo purus, porttitor eu vestibulum nec, vehicula congue ligula. Aenean ornare ac arcu sit amet vehicula. In molestie, lacus et vulputate vehicula, leo elit consectetur sem, sit amet rutrum mauris elit non dui. Vivamus viverra metus id venenatis commodo. Mauris blandit pellentesque ipsum non sollicitudin. Praesent lobortis velit quis nibh auctor, vitae dapibus elit commodo.</p>
        <p>Donec eget tellus id lacus bibendum cursus. Duis in ultricies urna. Aliquam lacinia, libero sed laoreet rhoncus, metus mauris placerat odio, sollicitudin sollicitudin diam justo vel mauris. Vestibulum non lacus lectus. Aenean interdum sagittis erat in iaculis. Nunc fermentum nisl at dui ultrices, sit amet viverra tellus tincidunt. Praesent at mauris eleifend, aliquet quam id, laoreet justo. Nulla malesuada finibus dui ac luctus. Vestibulum facilisis justo fermentum tincidunt efficitur. Maecenas suscipit ligula neque, sit amet pharetra magna placerat id. Suspendisse potenti. Donec erat ex, gravida sit amet risus nec, cursus facilisis ante. Proin ac massa accumsan, ullamcorper erat ac, laoreet orci. Nulla sollicitudin urna enim, nec porttitor tortor egestas ut. Etiam at justo quis metus maximus ultricies quis eu quam. Integer gravida nisl sem, nec porta tellus consequat eget.</p>
        <p>Quisque cursus, metus a sollicitudin pharetra, lorem odio fringilla arcu, non eleifend urna tellus vel nibh. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam a rutrum est. Etiam et sem vitae sapien tempor rutrum nec vulputate ex. Vestibulum eu vehicula tortor. Curabitur nulla velit, bibendum id varius non, pulvinar lobortis mi. Praesent tempor ex vel odio posuere, sed semper enim lacinia.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know a solution or a work-around that addresses the styling of this particular example?

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you. It is a common problem to run into on some devices. Hope that helps.

```
 .fixed {
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515694346937-94d85e41e6f0');
  background-attachment:scroll;
  background-position:left bottom;
  background-size:cover;
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.fixed').css('background-position', 'left ' + -((scrolledY)) + 'px');
});
```

Comment: No, that does not work. Try it out on CodePen and you'll see.

Comment: @Tom I just updated it. If you want to take a look it should work now. That is just odd it is not working on your device because I tested it and it worked great. This should force it to be a fixed background now.

Comment: No, this does not work, either. It fills the background of the entire page with the image. That is not what is intended. Did you look at the example on CodePen to see how it behaved before you suggested the CSS you've provided? Look at the CodePen as it is now. The Lorem Ipsum text is to appear against a white background. The background image is for the DIV in the center only, not the entire page. Open the CodePen in Firefox on your mobile device and you'll see how it should behave. Then open it on Chrome on your mobile device and you'll see how it's failing. Desktop browsers are ok.

Comment: @Tom Got it to work. There are many reasons why It doesn't work and that is to do with the scroll behavior. There is a way around this using scroll behavior. Here is an example: https://codepen.io/thetechzach/pen/XQrmqR

Comment: Thanks for finding a solution, however it is incredibly janky. When I open your CodePen in Chrome on my Android, the image flashes as I scroll and it updates incredibly slowly. It's not a good solution from a performance standpoint. There surely must be a CSS solution. If there isn't, then it's possible your JavaScript solution could be improved with calls to requestAnimationFrame. I can take a stab at that. But CSS would be better.

Comment: Also, the image shouldn't repeat; the proposed solution repeats the image.

Comment: I've updated the HTML example here and on CodePen to demonstrate two different divs with two different images.